# Can I merge two Microsoft Word documents reliably with Subversion?

Tags: svn, merge, ms-word

We have concurrent edits happening on Word documents and I want to make sure that Subversion can handle merging .doc files. Do you know if Subversion handles merges of Word documents well?

Answer (score 19):

Use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) merge utility with the [xdocdiff](http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiff/e/index.html) plugin to compare and merge Office documents

Comment: What does xdocdiff do for me?

Comment: Yes this didn't help me either. It does purportedly compare (ie. DIFF) word docs but does NOT merge.

Comment: I'm guessing back in 2008 this was a preferred solution, but nowadays TortoiseSVN should be able to invoke MS Word itself to use it as a nicer diff tool, right?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/152) in its default installation to view diffs and perform merges of Word documents, it just opens up Word and uses Word's own review/changes mode to do it.

Edit: By default it also has diffing capabilities for PowerPoint, Excel, OpenOffice and StarOffice formats. (Check the TortoiseSVN\Diff-Scripts directory).

Comment: Indeed the default installation does nice diff's using MS Word itself. However, I haven't been able to get it to do a 3-way-merge yet - even though it seems this should be possible using the `merge-doc.js` that's included. How do I trigger that?

Comment: I actually have no idea, though the first thing to check would be to see if Word itself using the UI can do a 3 way diff. Maybe with track changes and such it could (as two sets of changes). Haven't tried or tested it yet.

Answer (score 5):

I would add the [svn:needs-lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html) property to Word documents stored in Subversion so that people are required to lock the file before editing it. This will go a long way to prevent merge conflicts.

This is what we do at work and it works great. (We don't have a choice about having to use Word documents, thus this solution rather than changing the file type.)

Answer (score 1):

Word documents are binary, so, no. Are the editors knowledgeable enough that they can be taught how to use a plain-text format like reStructuredText or LaTeX?

Comment: Lyx is a pretty great alternitive to straight LaTex.
It does still have the whole what you get is what you mean. (and that's hard for people who are used ot WYSIWYG))
But it's closer to WYSIWYG, but it's underlying formate is plain text (almost direct LaTex form my quick look at it)

Answer (score 1):

No: since Word uses a binary file format, svn cannot merge the files at all.

However, Word itself has a merge feature. You might try that if you have to resolve a merge conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can save docx documents to a "Flat OPC" XML format using Word (Save As .. XML document).

This way you get a plain text file.

What you'll need to watch out for though, is that the relationship id's don't get corrupted.

For example:

- user A adds an image (or a hyperlink, or a comment, or a footnote etc) to the document, and does an svn commit.
- user B (without svn updating) adds one of those things in Word, saves as xml, then does svn update.

User B is unlikely to be able to open the document in Word at this point, so he better not commit it.  If you can control for this, or are prepared to manually fix the problems, you'll be ok.

Otherwise, you could consider something like my Plutext collaboration software, which shreds the document and versions its constituent bits, in Alfresco.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a non binary format like Html

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a Word plugin that uses SharpSVN to connect to a repository. At current state it is kind of complicated to create and to select new documents but that shouldnt be a big issue.

So when you (finally) have a document in the repository it is quite simple to commit and to update from any revision. You can compare and merge those .docx files with Word's built in compare or merge features. Quite simple actually. Hope to get it done the next weeks or so.

Answer (score 0):

This page  http://newgeeks.blogspot.com/2006/08/word-document-management-using-svn.html
gives infromation step-by-step on how to use totoiseSVN for version management of Microsoft Word Document.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Subversion to automatically merge Word documents. There is no 3-way merge support (even with Tortoise SVN). If you are not tied to Word, you can use an online doc editor, like the [Revisionator](https://revisionator.com). It supports 3-way merging of wysiwyg documents. Also other revision control features (diffing, forking, etc).