# does subversion support word, excel, powerpoint docs?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Does subversion support word, excel and powerpoint documents? "support" here means having history available and I can get old version out from the subversion. It will be nice if I can diff different versions. 
thanks,

Comment: yes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90202/can-i-merge-two-microsoft-word-documents-reliably-with-subversion) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810/is-version-control-ie-subversion-applicable-in-document-tracking)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, and TortoiseSVN supports diffing for Word and Excel really well, by invoking those app's native document comparison functions (not sure about PowerPoint).

Comment: Will it use the native diff to automatically merge when you update a working copy?  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can store binary files using `svn`. But you will not be able to `diff` them from the command line.

See [How do I tell subversion to treat a file as a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73797/how-do-i-tell-subversion-to-treat-a-file-as-a-binary-file) for advice on the mechanics.

Comment: Note that for most binary files, `svn` will automatically handle it correctly, and it will require no special treatment.

Comment: No. As far as SVN is concerned, the files are still opaque blobs so it doesn't so the sort of automatic merging that it would do for plain text files.