# SVN or Mercurial for Branching a Word Document Among Departments

Tags: svn, mercurial, ms-word

I have a company manual that I'm trying to keep under version control and I could use some advice.  The manual needs to go to different departments, and while certain areas of the manual are the same no matter what department it goes to, some sections are different for Accounting, HR, IT, etc.

Is it possible using branching to have a manual whereby I can have the manual in a /trunk, and then create branches for each individual department -- or something similar?  I don't want to have a different word document for each department as much of the manual is the same.

So my goal is that if I find a typo in a section that's the same for all departments, then I'd like to be able to correct it once globally as opposed to have to make the change in five different word documents.

But I'm also concerned about how to work with the specific sections of the manual that are different. If there's an area where there are examples that are department-specific, how do I make it so that I can have one version (branch?) with Accounting Dept.-specific examples and another version (branch?) that has IT Dept.-specific examples?

And if branching/merging is the way to go, is mercurial a better option than SVN? I'm new to version control and I have used SVN sparingly and I'm generally happy, but the one time I needed to merge was not a pleasant experience. I've read that people seem happier with mercurial vs. svn for merging and while I don't want this question to be about SVN vs Mercurial, is it easier to branch/merge with Mercurial vs. SVN in my specific situation?

Comment: Use a document management system that caters this problem.

Comment: I agree with jpartogi, take a look at what alfresco has to offer http://www.alfresco.com/products/dm/

Answer (score 2):

I'll go two steps further than what Will Hughes proposed. Instead of splitting the document into n individual documents:

- Use a [master document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-master-document-and-subdocuments-HP005187002.aspx) to group each of the sub-documents. One master for each "branch"
- Use the MS-Word built-in revision history management. It's quite powerful and handy when you learn how to use it.

That way, you'll provide only one document to your users, that contains all the needed parts for their departement, and you'll benefit of a per-section revision control.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this will work as you intend.

Word .doc files are a binary format, which is not suitable to the kind of merging that you're trying to do.

Word .docx files are actually a zip file, containing the document markup, and other embedded items. (Go ahead, rename a .docx file to .zip, and then open it using your favourite zip tool).

A Word template *may* get you part way, but I'd say you'll have more trouble maintaining it than it's worth, and you won't have the ability to merge back and forth.

Your best bet is probably to just split your document into 'company wide' and 'department specific' documents.

When a new employee comes onboard - you simply give them the company-wide policies, plus the policies applicable to their department.

So,

- Initech Policies

  - Confidentiality Agreement
  - Codes of Practice
  - Grooming & Dress Code
- Initech IT Department Policies

  - Network Security
- Initech Human Resources Department Policies

  - Filling Vacancies

Comment: Actually, [you can merge word documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90202/can-i-merge-two-microsoft-word-documents-reliably-with-subversion). TortoiseSVN will just open Word and use its built-in compare/merge features.

Comment: And, since TortoiseHg has copied all the merge scripts that TortoiseSVN uses, you will get the same merge functionality from Subversion and Mercurial - none if you use plain version control, and merge of docs if you use the tortoise.